# Magento 2 how to override Magento\Directory\Block\Data using preferences?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, form-validation, override-block

This is my code but the block is not overrided

My di file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Block\Data" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Directory\Data" />    
</config>
```

My PHP file :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Directory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue = null, $name = 'country_id', $id = 'country', $title = 'Country')
    {
        echo "test"; exit;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app/code/Vendor_name/MOdule_name/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Block\Data" type="Vendor_name\Module_name\Block\Data" />
</config>
```

and in your file app/code/Vendor_name\Module_name\Block\Data.php

```
 <?php
 
namespace Vendor_name\Module_name\Block;
 
class Data extends \Magento\Directory\Block\Data
{
    //overrider you file here
}
?>
```

hope this helps if yes then up vote please